# How do I get and use the public/private keys of users in Hyperledger v1.0?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I read that in Hyperledger v1, encryption and channels can be used to enforce privacy.

I want to try the encryption approach to accomplish this.  Since all registered users have private/public keys, I plan to use the public keys of users to encrypt some data (later I plan to combine this with symmetric cryptography to make it more efficient).

In addition, I plan to use the private key of the invoker of a function to perform  decryption.

How do I get the public/private keys inside the chaincode?  In addition, I also plan to perform encryption/decryption in NodeJS (outside the chaincode) since I'm using the NodeJS SDK for Hyperledger v1.  How do I get the public/private keys through NodeJS?

Answer (score 2):

While using NodeSDK you simply load keys from theirs location on disk and to obtain signer (client) certificate you can use API from `ChaincodeStubInterface` interface which provided you while chaincode is invoked:

```
// GetCreator returns `SignatureHeader.Creator` (e.g. an identity)
// of the `SignedProposal`. This is the identity of the agent (or user)
// submitting the transaction.
GetCreator() ([]byte, error)
```

Comment: Thanks @artem-barger.  Does the GetCreator provide also the private key of the invoker?  I plan to use the private key in query functions so that the caller of the query can decrypt any data that was encrypted with his/her public key.

Comment: If I need to get the public key of another user (not the invoker of the function) inside a chaincode, I think GetCreator will not address this.  Is there a similar function to GetCreator but provides the public key of another user?

Comment: No it doesn't provide a private key, no one should be able to receive an access to private keys (otherwise they won't be private).

Comment: And no, there is no way of acquiring public keys from chaincode.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think that you should know how are those keys created. There are different ways for it, but Hyperledger Fabric gives you two tools to create these keys:

- Cryptogen: this tool is used to generate the cryptographic material (x509 certs) for your network entities. These certificates are representative of identities, and they allow for sign/verify authentication to take place as our entities communicate and transact.
- Fabric CA: a component of the Fabric, i.e. the CA that will issue certificates for each member.

Then, once you have the keys, you should manage them. The Fabric project makes it easier thanks to the [MSP](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/msp.html). When you create a channel, you define the public keys of the peers and the keys of the issuers of those certificates. Then, Fabric manages them to verify the transactions.

The Membership service provider (MSP) offers us the possibility of abstracting from all the cryptographic mechanisms and protocols of validation, authentication verification and signature.